# Tridion Upgrade from 5.3 to 2011 SP1

Tags: configuration, cme

We have upgraded Tridion 5.3 to 2011 SP1. After upgrade we are facing one issue with rich text editor. If we create any new component having rich text editor then after saving the component the text entered in rich text editor became empty.

We have applied the similar fix mentioned in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219267/tridion-2011-filtering-xslt-on-formatting-feature-window

and things starts working but the main issue is that we need to do it in all the schemas whereever we have used the rich text.

So is there any way by which we can apply it on single place and reflected in all the places?

Answer (score 7):

First, if this happens as a consequence of an upgrade, do make sure you let Tridion Customer Support know about it - it might be a known upgrade issue, with an easy fix.

Second, that solution indeed requires that ALL RTF fields be changed. You can automate this (pretty simple change if you have anyone that can use the Tridion API) to loop through your schemas, find RTF fields, and modify the XSLT settings.

If you don't have anyone that can use the Tridion API, then you're stuck with doing it one-by-one - tedious, but not the worst job in the world.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I created a tool to export from Tridion 5.2 and import into Tridion 2011, works fine, still lot of issues need to be addressed before, like common empty tag issue etc...